# Django. How to write a filter for the current user?

Tags: django, django-admin, instance-variables, django-users, django-filters

The listings application has a Listing table:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    realtor = models.ForeignKey(Realtor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Риэлтор')
    region = models.CharField(default="Чуйская", max_length=100, verbose_name='Область')
    city = models.CharField(default="Бишкек", max_length=100, verbose_name='Город')
    district = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100, verbose_name='Район')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Заголовок')
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, verbose_name='Адрес')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание') 
    stage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Этажность')
    rooms = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Количество комнат')   
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, verbose_name='Гараж')
    sqmt = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Площадь')
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Основное фото')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 1')
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 2')
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 3')
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 4')
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 5')
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, verbose_name='Фото 6')
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Публично')
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата публикации')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
```

In the realtors application there is a Realtor model:

```
class Realtor(models.Model):
    user_name = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Пользователь', related_name='realtor')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Имя')
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Описание')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Телефон')
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Email')
    is_mvp = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Реэлтор месяца')
    hire_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True, verbose_name='Дата приёма на работу')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Риэлтор'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Риэлторы'
```

In the accounts application, there is a function that in the personal account should only display ads of the current user when he is in the system:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from listings.models import Listing
    from realtors.models import Realtor

    def dashboard(request):
      listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(user_name=request.user)

      paginator = Paginator(listings, 6)
      page = request.GET.get('page')
      paged_listings = paginator.get_page(page)

      context = {
        'listings': paged_listings
      }
      return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context
)
```

How to correctly register this filter so that everything works so that the current user’s ads are displayed:

```
listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(user_name=request.user)
```

At the moment, this error:

Cannot resolve keyword 'user_name' into field. Choices are: address, city, description, district, garage, id, is_published, list_date, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, photo_4, photo_5, photo_6, photo_main, price, realtor, realtor_id, region, rooms, sqmt, stage, title

Who is not difficult, please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's great that you have included code and a fiddle, but I think it is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's no `user_name` field in `Listing`, it's an error to try and filter on that.

Instead, you presumably are trying to filter on the realtor, which can done with a [lookup that spans relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
listings = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(realtor__user_name=request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

`user_name` is a field on the Realtor model, not the Listing. Those two models are connected by a ForeignKey, so you need to traverse that relationship using the double-underscore syntax.

```
Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date').filter(realtor__user_name=request.user)
```

Note though that `user_name` is a very odd name for that field; it's not the name, it's the User object itself. It should be called just `user`.